# How to find og combine rows who have continuous time columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

This problem has become a bit of a headache for me. I'm setting up a BI project for health care visitors, but sadly their registration of data is pretty poor. In the example shown in the figure I have the following columns:

1. ID number for the specific person
2. food type
3. start date of that specifik food type
4. end date

For Person A, the health care visitors have registreted the same foodtype 3 consecutive times even though it should only be registrated as one long period. I want to combine these 3 rows, so that I only have one row containing the ID, food type, the FIRST start date and the LAST end date (italic) IF the end date of the current column is the same as the new start date of the next column for each specific food type. The same applies for Person B, where the 3 rows should be combined to 1 row with start and end date (italic)

- **ID FoodType    StartDate   EndDate**
- [PersonA] ... S002 ... ***04-11-2014*** ... 10-11-2014
- [PersonA] ... S002 ... 10-11-2014 ... 08-01-2015
- [PersonA] ... S002 ... 08-01-2015 ... ***24-03-2015***
- [PersonA] ... S006 ... 24-03-2015 ... 1753-01-01
- [PersonB] ... S002 ... ***06-08-2013***  ... 16-08-2013
- [PersonB] ... S002 ... 16-08-2013 ... 26-08-2013
- [PersonB] ... S002 ... 26-08-2013 ... ***12-12-2013***
- [PersonB] ... S008 ... 12-12-2013 ... 11-02-2014

So I will get this table:

- **ID Food type   StartDate   EndDate**
- [PersonA] ... S002 ... ***04-11-2014*** ... ***24-03-2015***
- [PersonA] ... S006 ... 24-03-2015 ... 1753-01-01
- [PersonB] ... S002 ... ***06-08-2013***  ... ***12-12-2013***
- [PersonB] ... S008 ... 12-12-2013 ... 11-02-2014

Here is the SQL query to create the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CombineDates](
[ID] [varchar](36) NULL,
[FoodType] [varchar](10) NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NULL) ON [PRIMARY]

insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate])
values('Person A','S002','2014-11-04 00:00:00.000','2014-11-10 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate])
values('Person A','S002','2014-11-04 00:00:00.000','2014-11-10 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person A','S002','2014-11-10 00:00:00.000','2015-01-08 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person A','S002','2015-01-08 00:00:00.000','2015-03-24 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person B','S002','2013-08-06 00:00:00.000','2013-08-16 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person B','S002','2013-08-16 00:00:00.000','2013-08-26 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person B','S002','2013-08-26 00:00:00.000','2013-12-12 00:00:00.000')
insert into CombineDates([ID],[FoodType],[StartDate],[EndDate]) 
values('Person B','S008','2013-12-12 00:00:00.000','2014-02-11 00:00:00.000')

select * from CombineDates
```

Hope you can help me. Thank you and

BR,

Jesper

Comment: Your sample code is SQL Server, so I added that tag.  You should also tag with the particular version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: What's you SQL Server version? The data looks like a Slowly Changing Dimension and then the task is to normalize it. Is it properly maintained, i.e. no gaps or overlapping periods?

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio 2008 R2. The periods can overlap but not for the same food type. If they register a food type that is not ended the specific food type will end and start another of the same day - that's why I want to combine those records with same start and enddates. You can, however, fill in other food types even though you have one food type that is not ended. This means that you can only have one type of food "open" at a time but you can also have multiple food types "open" at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On approach to this is to identify each time a person starts a new food type.  You can do this by recognizing that record does not overlap with any records *before* it.  Then, groups of consecutive values are identified by counting the number of "starting" records before it.

This uses a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2012+, you would do:

```
with cdf as (
      select cd.*
             (case when exists (select 1
                                from combinedates cd2
                                where cd2.id = cd.id and cd2.foodtype = cd.foodtype and
                                      cd2.startdate < cd.startdate and
                                      cd2.enddate >= cd.startdate
                               )
                   then 1 else 0
              end) as StartFlag
      from combinedates cd
     )
select id, foodtype, min(startdate) as startdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from (select cdf.*,
             sum(StartFlag) over (partition by id, foodtype order by startdate) as grp
      from cdf
     ) cdf
group by id, foodtype, grp
```

A note about naming.  A column called `id` should be a unique/primary key column in a table where it is defined.  This is just an expectation of anyone reading the code, in the same way that a column called `StartDate` is not an integer. (I wouldn't have such a column, because my style is to have the primary key include the table name.)

In your table, this column should be called `PersonId`.  I would define the table more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE PersonFoods (
    PersonFoodId int identity(1, 1) not null primary key,
    PersonId varchar(36),
    FoodType varchar(10),
    StartDate datetime,
    EndDate datetime
);
```

And given that you are not using time components, the `datetime` values should perhaps be just `date`.

Comment: This was helpful! What if I have 5 records of the same food type for person A. The first 3 are consecutive og the 2 latter are consecutive to one another. I want to group the records, giving me the min(startdate) and max(enddate) of the first 3 consucutive records and the min(startdate) and max(enddate) of the last 2 consucutive records, return 2 rows at the end. Can you do that?